# Cannot add dependency to sibling monorepo package using lerna

Tags: npm, lerna, monorepo

How do I get one monorepo package to have a dependency on another using lerna?

I have a directory structure like this in my monorepo:

```
packages
  pkg-a  (package name is @foo/pkg-a)
  pkg-b  (package name is @foo/pkg-b)
```

I want `@foo/pkg-a` to have `@foo/pkg-b` as a dependency, so I attempt the command:

```
npx lerna add @foo/pkg-b --scope=@foo/pkg-a
```

Lerna adds the dependency in `packages/pkg-a/package.json` as expected, but it then seemingly attempts to do an `lerna bootstrap` afterward, and it outputs the error:

> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@foo%2fpkg-b - Not found

It's completely failing to actually link to the local dependency. When `npx lerna boostrap` manually afterward, I continue getting the same error.

It seems like either lerna documentation is either incredibly bad, lerna is very broken, or I'm completely missing the point of what it's supposed to let me do. How do I get one monorepo package to be linked to another using lerna?

**Update**

The `lerna link` command seems to work to get things in the right state after the partially-failing `lerna add` command. Is there a way to get  `lerna add` to do the right thing in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

[This thread might be helpful](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/200)

> If my-sibling hasn't been published yet you'll need to add that dependency yourself by editing the JSON file. Once the dependency is added lerna bootstrap will create the "link" regardless of whether my-sibling has been published.

The short story is that if the sibling package has not yet been published to npm you will need to manually add it to the appropriate `package.json` dependencies section. From there, running `lerna bootstrap` will handle the internal linking.

For instance:

```
// pkg-a/package.json


{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@foo/pkg-b": "*"
  }
}
```